# More than one Pages library?

Tags: content-type, page-layout, publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing

We have requirements where we need to add multiple pages libraries on a site, but this seems impossible to do via both the GUI and code.

Is it all possible / supported ?

Comment: You can store aspx pages on any document library. So, What's the problem?

Comment: Store, yes, but not create. Try creating article pages in a Documents library and see what happens.

Comment: What happens? I've just created a document library "articles" added a web part page "simple.aspx", opened it on IE, edited and saved.

Comment: In SharePoint Foundation 2013 go to site content, add an App, Wiki page library. But actually you can host whatever aspx page on whatever document library. The difference is that you don't have a button to add the page, but it can be done.

Comment: How did you add the page ? I did the same on a documents library, and tried to create an aritcle page (publishing), and get an exception: Application error when access /_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx, Error=Value does not fall within the expected range.  
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile(SPList list, String url, Boolean createAsListItem)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.NewPageItemSave(String pageName, PageLayout pageLayout, String folderUrl, Boolean redirect)

Comment: I created a simple page on the page library, then copied it to document library using Windows Explorer (WebDav client). You can also copy the page using SharePoint Designer. Pages can also be added to document libraries using wsp's (SharePoint solutions). Ultimatly you can create aspx pages using NotePad, upload them to document library are you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, but we want to avoid doing things like this. The editors who use this solution just want to click "add a new page". Not create from other libraries, download and then upload.Looking for a template identical to that Pages use

Comment: Then go to site content, add an App, Wiki page library

Comment: I don't need a Wiki pages library, it doesn't work like Pages, as I have tried to say about 10 times now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is: No, it is not possible to create another library with the same functionality as Pages on a publishing site.

Comment: @llyas  The answer to this question is: Yes, it is not possible to create another library with the same functionality as Pages on a publishing site.

Answer (score 2):

Web Part Pages and Wiki pages can be stored in any document library as long as the appropriate content type has been added to the library via its settings.

However, the library actually named "Pages" is created & maintained by the Publishing feature. Attempting to rename or delete it will probably not work and/or cause problems.

If you want to create Publishing (i.e. - 'Article') pages, but NOT put them in the default Pages library, then you can simply create a normal document library and then add the appropriate content type to it afterwards. Any content type added to a library will show up as an option under the "New Document" button in the ribbon. With SP2013, you can even use the JSLink option to add buttons to your list interface, thereby creating each content type with a single click.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Everybody I ask suggest to simply add a content type to a document library, but try to add the content type of article page and try to create a page with that content type in the document library: It will give an exception. As far as I can see there is no way to create a new library (of course with another name than pages) that functions like a Pages - library.

Comment: That sounds like some sort of issue with your environment. Normally, as long as the publishing feature is turned on, you should be able to add the content type to any library. Make sure the page layouts are available via site settings.

Comment: The content type is added perfectly, but it is when you create an article page in a document library (that is not Pages) you will get the exception when trying to save.

Comment: Sounds like either a feature or page layout isn't enabled. I'll poke around and see what I can find.

Comment: Cool. I poked around all day, and found no way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Pages content types, such as Enterprise Wiki Page, to any document library but you will not be able to create any documents using them.  These content types only work in the Pages library.  SharePoint 2013 on-prem.